# How to override a plugin dependency in a Gradle conventions plugin

Tags: gradle, lombok

I'm using Gradle's conventions as described here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

And in the convention plugin, I'm applying a plugin (`io.freefair.gradle:lombok-plugin:6.5.1`) however I now need to override a dependency that it uses (I need `org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22` not `1.18.24`)

I've tried this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.freefair.gradle:lombok-plugin:6.5.1'
    ...
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
}
```

But version `1.18.24` was used. I've also tried adding this to my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'billforward.java-conventions'
}
```

but still `1.18.24` was used.

As an aside, the two underlying issues I'm trying to solve are:

- https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/549 - Resolved in  6.5 of lombok-plugin
- https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3180 - Broken in 1.18.24 of lombok

Comment: This is the line of code where the lombok-plugin adds the dependency on Lombok: https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/blob/8a076c65ac957598430aad073c463b9f8f4bdced/lombok-plugin/src/main/java/io/freefair/gradle/plugins/lombok/LombokBasePlugin.java#L21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lombok version used by `io.freefair.lombok` can be customized by using the `lombok` extension property:

```
plugins {
  id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.5.1"
}

lombok.version = "1.18.22"
```

This is documented here: https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/6.5.1/reference/#_io_freefair_lombok_base

Adding lombok itself to the buildscript classpath (or the runtime classpath of your gradle plugin) will not do anything.

Comment: Perfect, that solved the problem for me with upgrading. Next issue is that https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/549 doesn't actually fix the problem!